# missing maven dependencies in RCP product using tycho

Tags: eclipse-plugin, tycho

I'm using tycho for creating a RCP product but as soon as I set the plugin pom
packaging to **eclipse-plugin** ,maven dependency library removes from project and cause lots of error because of missing library.I've tried running maven both  on terminal and eclipse and they have the same result.Does anyone know how to fix this problem and is there someone that exported a complete RCP plugin using tycho?

thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "maven dependency library removes from project"? I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Tycho does not use maven dependencies to compile your plugin. Dependencies are specified using the plugin Manifest file as with a normal eclipse plugin.

In Eclipse, dependencies will be found using the workspace (assuming m2e & tycho configurators are installed) or from the plugins defined in your target platform (typically the eclipse installation). On the command line, these dependencies should be available in a p2 repository - these can be defined in a target definition file or in a normal maven repository block in the pom file with the p2 layout. See [1] for details on using these.

It is possible to configure Tycho to consider pom dependencies but this will not work when exporting an RCP application - dependencies need to be found in a p2 repository.

[1] http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card#Repository_providing_the_context_of_the_build